# Python crashes when importing pyqt

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt4

I downloaded the PyQt 64-bit wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) and extracted the files using 7-Zip into `python3/Lib/sitepackages`.

I then put the folder named "pyqt4" in "purelib" into `site-packages`, and put the DLL files on my path.

I installed the missing DLL, which I found by opening designer, and put it in the pyqt4 folder (now in site-packages).

I tried importing PyQt4, and it worked.

I tried importing `PyQt4.QtGui`. Not so lucky, Python just crashed.

I'm running 64-bit Python on 64-bit computer on Windows 10.

Comment: It would be very useful to know what error message you got.

Comment: try using x64 version of pyqt install package, might work - https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.5.0-x64.exe/download

Answer (score 0):

From the link  you have provided ,it seems you have downloaded the  4.11 build of PyQt4. This build is having some issues [Read this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/654) . I suggest you to update and install the latest PyQt4 from [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). I hope this helps you.

Comment: The PyQt4 download page you linked to clearly states: "binary installers for Windows are no longer provided". That is why the OP is using these unofficial installers. It would have been more helpful to link to the [PyQt4 sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/), which still has all the official installers for earlier versions.